# Why does using importlib.util break type comparisons?

Tags: python

I have a module (`some_module`) with a file (`somefile`), containing an object I want to instantiate (`foo`).

```
from collections import namedtuple

foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['a', 'b'])
```

In certain situations I only know the path to this file so have been importing [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path):

```
import importlib.util as iu

spec = iu.spec_from_file_location("some_module.somefile", 'path/to/some_module/somefile.py')
mod = iu.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)

var1 = mod.foo(1 ,2)
```

This worked fine at first but in my unit testing I discovered that `type(var)` was not equal to the type of the original ie:

```
from some_module.somefile import foo

var2 = foo(1, 2)

print(type(var1) is type(var2))
print(isinstance(var1, var2.__class__)
```

Prints only `False`'s, despite the fact that it appears that both `var1` & `var2` are functionally equivalent.

EDIT:
I'm using python 3.9.5 and in my test code, the construction functions for `var1` & `var2` are in separate .py files, they get imported into a unit test which tries to check if both the objects are the same.

Comment: "both var1 & var2 are functionally equivalent" That doesn't make them *identical*. You've effectively told Python to run the same code twice, creating a new ``foo`` definition each time.

Comment: I see, so type definitions look to the construction, and when it was run to define a type? I suppose the simplest solution is probably to extend my unit test to assert that they're functionally equivalent (comparing __ dir__ of both?) rather than asserting they're of the same type

Comment: "I see, so type definitions look to the construction, and when it was run to define a type?" In short, types are objects. Defining the same type twice gives you two separate types, just like instantiating the same object twice gives you two separate objects.